# Corona SDK Error: physics.start() has not been called

Tags: lua, coronasdk, physics-engine

I have my main.lua pointing me to level one, i have an onCollision function which takes me to level two, but when i go to level two, everything loads fine except the physics engine. I get an error in the console saying ERROR: physics.start() has not been called. But at the top of level2.lua i have declared:

```
local physics = require( "physics" )
physics.start()
```

This is the end of my level1.lua file:

```
function scene:hide( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase
    if event.phase == "will" then
        -- Called when the scene is on screen and is about to move off screen
        physics.stop()
    elseif phase == "did" then
        -- Called when the scene is now off screen
    end
end
function scene:destroy( event )
    -- Called prior to the removal of scene's "view" (sceneGroup)
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    package.loaded[physics] = nil
    physics = nil
end
```

The start of my level2.lua is this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------           
--
-- level2.lua
--
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene()

-- include Corona's "physics" library
local physics = require ("physics")
physics.start()

-- forward declarations and other locals
local screenW, screenH, halfW, halfH = display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight,     display.contentWidth*0.5, display.contentHeight*0.5
local centerY, centerX = display.contentCenterY, display.contentCenterX
```

Why am i getting this error even though i have quite clearly started physics? I've tried copying the exact same code from level1.lua to level2.lua but im still getting the same results.

Comment: Move the physics.start() into your scene:create(event) function.

Comment: I've tried that, it doesn't work, i still get the same error message.

Comment: It could be a lot of things. Maybe a listener who utilizes the physics module that you are not properly shutting down/ removing from the old scene? That way when you remove the physics on the other scene the listener could trigger the error as you DONT have physics on. But as said the error could be in a lot of places, not able to find anything in the code provided.

Comment: Thanks, i realized i had an event listener that wasn't removed. I still get the error but everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a collision listener in my scene:create function.

```
    function onCollision( event )
    if(event.object1.myName == "name" and event.object2.myName == "name" ) then
        timer.performWithDelay( 3000, nextLevel, 1 )
        return true
    end
end
```

I think that this function kept on calling the physics package and returned the error when I progressed to the next level because I had called

```
physics.stop()
```

I managed to fix it by removing the event listener in line 4 of the function:

```
    function onCollision( event )
    if(event.object1.myName == "ball" and event.object2.myName == "finThree" ) then
        timer.performWithDelay( 3000, nextLevel, 1 )
                Runtime:removeEventListener( "collision", onCollision ) -- I remove the eventListener here.
        return true
    end
end
```

I still get the same error message as before, but the problem seems to be fixed. I know this won't be a fix for everyone, but it worked for me and hopefully it'll work for others suffering the same problem as me.

Thanks to Frozire for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

Putting code that you expect to run in main chunk will only execute the very first time the module loads.  If you re-enter the scene later and have not un-required the scene.

You need to do a physics.start() in scene:create() to allow you to  add Bodies there.  But you don't want them to start interacting until the scene is loaded.  I call physics.start() in scene:create() an then immediately pause it with physics.pause().  Then in my scene:show()'s did phase, I call physics.start() again to start my interactions going.  That way you can re-enter the scene without having to recreate it and have your physics started.